# Excel source data wrong direction

Tags: vba, excel, graph

I get parameter not valid at line `.SeriesCollection(1).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle`

The thing is that my Source Data doesn't seem to work, or rather, does work, but not like I think it would.

I'm unable to add picture, so I'll try the best I can describe what is happening and what I'm looking for.

To help, here's a table

```
3    season A      col B  col C col D    col E   col F   col G
4    2010 - 2011       9,66   1,25  10,9    10175   20837   31012
5    2011 - 2012       7,34   0,62  8       8110    21884   29994
6    2012 - 2013       7,84   0,18  8       6840    17943   24783
```

Which `seasonCount = 3`

What I have : The series are horizontaly and depend on the number of season. Like for this table above, I get 3 seriesCollection. And again for this table, `seriesCollection(1) is D4:G4`

What I want Vertical Series, SourceData is `"D4:G" & seasonCount + 3` which would be D4 to G6. With `SeriesCollection(1) = "D4:D6"` I then delete collections corresponding to col E and col F and now `SeriesCollection(2) = "G4:G6"`

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
        (Left:=10, Width:=480, Top:=240, Height:=265)
    With .Chart
        .ChartType = xlLineMarkers

        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Results").Range("D4:G" & seasonCount + 3)

        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets("Results").Range("A4:A" & seasonCount + 3)
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Indice de rigueur hivernale"
        .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
        .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Weight = 4
        .SeriesCollection(1).Border.Weight = 0.75

        .SeriesCollection(2).Delete
        .SeriesCollection(2).Delete

        .SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
        .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Consommation de sel totale"

        With .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.349999994
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
        With .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With

        .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
        .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
        .SetElement (msoElementSecondaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Indice de rigueur hivernale"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).AxisTitle.Text = "Consommation de sel (tonnes)"
        .ChartStyle = 19
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Indice par rapport au sel total"
    End With
End With
```

EDIT**

I wasn't able to add a picture earlier but now I can. This is the results :
[image]

This is another table that is working perfectly fine, as you can see, there isn't much change in the code. The difference is the `seasonCount` variable and the fact that the X axis is now column A and not B.

Working Code and Graph :

[image: EDIT]

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
        (Left:=10, Width:=480, Top:=240, Height:=265)
    With .Chart
        .ChartType = xlLineMarkers

        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Results").Range("E4:H10")


        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets("Results").Range("B4:B10")
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Indice de rigueur hivernale"
        .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
        .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Weight = 4
        .SeriesCollection(1).Border.Weight = 0.75

        .SeriesCollection(2).Delete
        .SeriesCollection(2).Delete

        .SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
        .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Consommation de sel totale"

        With .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.349999994
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
        With .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With

        .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
        .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
        .SetElement (msoElementSecondaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Indice de rigueur hivernale"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).AxisTitle.Text = "Consommation de sel (tonnes)"
        .ChartStyle = 19
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Indice par rapport au sel total"
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Why can't you add a picture?  You have the rep.  Is the data sensitive?  If so, can you make it gibberish for example's sake?  I see no obvious reason that call would fail there.  If you want better control over the `Series` you should use `SeriesCollection.NewSeries` and manually set the `XValues` and `Values` to the `Range` that you want.  It provides much greater control than `SetSourceData`.  If you comment that line out, does it run correctly... or is more going wrong than that line?

Comment: You need to use `PlotBy` in `SetSourceData`, as in `.SetSourceData Source:=_range_, PlotBy:=xlColumns`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Byron Wall's, creating series manually with `.SeriesCollection.NewSeries` instead of `.SetSourceData` worked really well. Here's the working code

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
        (Left:=10, Width:=480, Top:=240, Height:=265)
    With .Chart
        .ChartType = xlLineMarkers

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Sheets("Results").Range("D4:D" & seasonCount + 3)
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets("Results").Range("A4:A" & seasonCount + 3)
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Indice de rigueur hivernale"
        .SeriesCollection(1).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
        .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Weight = 4
        .SeriesCollection(1).Border.Weight = 0.75

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(2).Values = Sheets("Results").Range("G4:G" & seasonCount + 3)
        .SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
        .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Consommation de sel totale"

        With .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.349999994
            .Transparency = 0
        End With
        With .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With

        .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
        .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
        .SetElement (msoElementSecondaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Indice de rigueur hivernale"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).AxisTitle.Text = "Consommation de sel (tonnes)"
        .ChartStyle = 19
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Indice par rapport au sel total"
    End With
End With
```